# how can i mantain a wrapper div height auto?

Tags: css

```
<style>
body{
 background:#FF9900;
 color:#FFFFFF;
 }
.wrapper{
    width:900px;
    height:auto;
    padding:0px;
    margin:auto;
    background:#000000;
    }
.header{
    width:900px;
    height:50px;
    float:left;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
   }
.body_content{
    width:900px;
    height:200px;
    float:left;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    }
.fotter{
    width:900px;
    height:50px;
    float:left;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px 0px 25px 0px;
    }   
</style>


   <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="body_content">Body Content</div>
    <div class="fotter">Footer</div>
    </div>
```

If i give a wrapper div height:"500px" i can see the background color black. But if i change the to height="auto" i cant see the color.

Can some one please help me with this ?

Please see here..[link text](http://202.53.11.62/css.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

Add `overflow: hidden` or `overflow: auto` to your `#wrapper` styles.

You have to do this, because containers with floated elements inside them don't have any height by default, so you have to use the above hack (or some other) to force the browser to give the container some height.

You can also add a `<div style="clear: both;"></div>` as the last element in your `#wrapper` and that should work also.

Comment: if i set it overflow: hidden or overflow: auto.. i'm getting a scroller

Comment: Here's the live site url i'm working on http://202.53.11.62/wrapper/  if i set the wrapper div height to 550px it shows the bgcolor fine but not when set to auto

Answer (score 0):

Is it because you have zero content?  Add 'lorem ipsum' and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>


<style>
body{
 background:#FF9900;
 color:#FFFFFF;
 }
#wrapper{
    width:900px;
    height:auto;
    padding:0px;
    margin:auto;
    background-color:#990000;
    clear:both;
    }
.header{
    width:900px;
    height:50px;
    float:left;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
   }
.body_content{
    width:900px;
    height:200px;
    float:left;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    }
.footer{
    width:900px;
    height:50px;
    float:left;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px 0px 25px 0px;
    }   
</style>

<body>
   <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="body_content">
      <p>Body Content</p>

    </div>
    <div class="footer">Footer</div>
    <hr/>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

hope this will solve the problem

Comment: add hr tag before closing div wrapper will solve problem