# i cont see the background color with out height of the wrapper div?

Tags: css

live site url i'm working on  [Click to see the site](http://202.53.11.62/wrapper/) if i set the wrapper div height to 550px it shows the bgcolor fine but not when set to auto

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can i mantain a wrapper div height auto ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265881/how-can-i-mantain-a-wrapper-div-height-auto)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best

Comment: Why <div class="content"> (and why "class"?) is float:left??

Comment: The requested URL /wrapper/ was not found on this server.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps your wrapper need `overflow:hidden`